# Can I use Git from the command line to manage an Android Project?

Tags: git, eclipse

I know that Eclipse has built in Git integration, but I'm so used to quick, simple Git commands from the command line.

Does Eclipse manage a git repository any differently than is done through the command line?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? This question doesn't belong on StackO, so I'm not sure where the appropriate place to ask it would if not here.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: Okay fair, edited for clarity.

Comment: as far as I can tell, [edited version](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/246103/2 "'Does Eclipse manage a git repository ant differently than is done through the command line?'") makes a better fit for SO than here

Comment: IDK, seems like splitting hairs to me. I always thought SO was more for solving specific problems with code examples etc. This seems like a more general question about how  Eclipse, AndroidSDK and git function.

Comment: yup, in the past I wouldn't even bother trying to figure tricky cases like that. But thorough analysis in [this meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go "Where does my git question go?") made it much easier to reason about

Comment: From that post regarding SO-esque questions: "The key point here is you are asking for something to type into the command line to do something." - My question doesn't really fit this profile, so I'm going to leave it here on PSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even having git in eclipse I still use command line git. The only operation I have managed to do right in eclipse was adding new files to index. In all other cases using command line is easier than fighting with UI. For me.

The main reason I have git in eclipse is that (I hope) it manages to understand "sudden" changes to source files which happen when I change the working tree from command line. Sometimes it's just easier to close eclipse, do all the git work (bisect, or some rebasing for example), then launch eclipse again.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does nothing else that this. It just handles it for you.

So you're good to go, if you want to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a lot of support built-in in the UI so anything you use in Eclipse would require less effort. In machine learning, information retrieval and psychology term, the search space in an UI or assisted environment is much less than the verbose command line.

In other words, by using Eclipse your brain works more in precision and result ranking mode than in recall and exhaustive search mode because you offload this out.

Comment: But functionally, the same?

Comment: Not exactly, but similar enough so that people should be allowed and free to use whatever they like.